# Rendering a python dict from a concatenated string in Jinja2

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

I'm playing around with Jinja templates for a JSON file I need to build.

I have a dict like this:

```
{'areaCode0': 000, 'areaCode1': 111, 'areaCode2': 222, 'numZones': 2}
```

The template is pretty simple:

```
{% for i in range(numZones) %}
"Foo": [{
        "bar": "{{ 'areaCode' ~ i|string }}"}],
```

This returns:

```
  "Foo": [{
            "bar": "areaCode0"}],
  "Foo": [{
            "bar": "areaCode1"}],
```

What I would like it to return is:

```
  "Foo": [{
            "bar": "000"}],
  "Foo": [{
            "bar": "111"}],
```

Any idea? Still new to this and would like to learn.

Comment: Want me to solve in python or jinja2

Comment: @U9-Forward this whole question is Jinja2

Comment: @roganjosh Yeah than why OP tags [tag:python]

Comment: @U9-Forward because it's a templating library written in, and generally for, Python? It's generally used in Flask

Comment: @roganjosh Ok i have no idea of jinja2 :), so you can answer it :D

Comment: @U9-Forward My apologies for maybe tagging this improperly. As I would like to render a value from a python dict I added the tag. I'll remove it.

Comment: @David I don't know jinja2, but as roganjosh says, i think can keep it

Comment: @U9-Forward there's a distinction between understanding the context and understanding the question :P

Comment: @roganjosh lol,yeah:)

Comment: I'm rolling back to `python` as a tag. I don't think it's inappropriate here. You may disagree; I won't get into a rollback war over it with you :)

Comment: I think you do something like `numZones.areaCode#` for accessing values in a dict. Right now you are just typing in a string. This post would be better if you posted a functioning code snippet that produces the result you're getting, from defining the dict to printing the result. That way we don't have to create that from scratch in order to help you with the solution.